# Z axis scrolling (explode effect)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, scroll, 3d, z-axis

I'm trying to do something like this https://craftprizeexhibition.loewe.com/ on scroll.

I used an example in codepen and I'm trying to adapt it because I'm deleloping a next.js app. The problem is that all the images go to the same place, I want more of an explode effect.

In my code, they are all moving in a perspective of 300px that I applied to the container.

How can I make this work?

Comment: _explode effect_ What do you mean by this? Those planes zooming in, this you are talking about? They use `webgl` and `gsap`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.